# Retrieving data from this pointer and storing in a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector

Below class workerClass has a `run` function which is called for every thread that is spawned. Every thread that runs has a seperate `id` `packetCount` and `packetDropped`. I wish to store this data seperately for all cores and retrieve them later **using global vector of objects in a different class**.

```
class workerClass
{

   private: 

   std::atomic<int> id;
   std::atomic<int> packetCount;
   std::atomic<int> packetDropped;

   void run(int id); 
};

std::vector<workerClass> worker; // My vector

void workerClass::run(int id)
{
   this->id = id;
   packetDropped; // store data of `this` pointer and packetDropped to vector of objects
}
```

If I try to `push_back(this)` which I know may not be correct gives me below error

> error: use of deleted function

I am open to better approaches if any.

Comment: Yes, you can. Have you tried it? (Incidentally, be aware that this->packetDropped = packetDropped;` does nothing. At best.)

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes. `workerClass adam; vector<workerClass> team; team.push_back(adam); team[0].run();`

Comment: @Beta thanks for this and I understand what you just mentioned I edited the answer if what I want is clear ?

Comment: In your post you do not ask a question. What problem are you trying to solve? Please, show the code that does not work.